# Proper way to use discord.utils.find in Discord PY

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello sorry this is my first time asking a question here so may be a little rough
I am  trying to use discord.utils.find to search a user in a server but it always returns None

`user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == 'Spades', message.guild.members)`
is the line being used I am trying to search for a user with the name of "Spades" and a tag of "#1600"
any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: There probably isn't a user with the _name_ of exactly Spades

Comment: @12944qwerty i mean im like 99% sure there is cause thats my username lol

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for loop, example

```py
# the user we are trying to find
user = 'Spades#1600'
# starting the for loop on all guild that the bot in
for g in client.guilds:
    # get the members from the guild
    for m in g.members:
        # If the user we are trying the find in the guild
        if m.name == user.split("#")[0] and user.discriminator == user.split("#")[1]:
            # we print it out
            print(f"{user} is in {g.name}!"
            continue # Checks if the user is in another guild
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with replacing `m.name` to `str(m)`

```
user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: str(m) == 'Spades#1600', message.guild.members)
```

or

```
user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == 'Spades' and m.discriminator == 1600, message.guild.members)
```

Comment: Hi im still getting the same error where it says it is = None

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the quotes on discriminator. So it will be `m.discriminator == "1600"`.

Comment: ahh sucks it seems that i still get the same error. thanks anyways

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you can use `discord.utils.get`. Take a loop to the api reference discord.py if you want.

Comment: weird. idk why it doesnt work but ill take a look at it

Comment: i tried something like ```member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name='Spades')``` but i got that same error

Comment: Did you enabled the intents on developer portal?

Comment: I gave it PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT just now. do i have to do anything to get it to work?

Comment: You must add intents to your code. `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())`

Comment: where exactly should i put that line of code?